# Command line calculator in C. What is wrong?

Tags: c

I have this code as a simple command line calculator in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

int num1, num2, result;
char op1;

/* convert 1st and 3st of the arguments into int */
/* assign the argv[1] to num1, assign the argv[2] to op1,
 assign the argv[3] to num2 */

if (argc == 4){
    sscanf(argv[1],"%d",&num1);
    scanf(argv[2],"%c",&op1);
    sscanf(argv[3],"%d",&num2);
}

else{   // if the input is wrong
    printf("Input Error\n");
}

switch (op1){

    case'+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        break;
    case'-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        break;
    case'x':
        result = num1 * num2;
        break;
    case'/':
        result = num1 / num2;
        break;
    case'%':
        result = num1 % num2;
        break;
    default: printf("Input Error!!!\n");
}
printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

After I complied the code and ran it. Some error happens.

For example, I use command: ./main 1 + 2 (Which should be 3)

The output is: 
Input Error!!!
0

And if I use command: ./main

The output is:
Input Error
Input Error!!!
0

I don't where is wrong. Please help!! Thank you so much!! I'm a completely beginner to C.

Comment: `scanf(argv[2],"%c",&op1);`?  You should be checking all calls to `sscanf()` return `1`.

Comment: In fact, I also tried sscanf(argv[2],"%c",&op1); but none of them works

Comment: Use the debugger to step through the code and find out why the code behaves the way it does.

Comment: So the logic of this code is correct? is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems:

1. You used `scanf` instead of `sscanf` for parsing a character.
2. You don't check the return value of those `sscanf`s.
3. The `switch` and the final `printf` should be *inside* the `if`, not outside it.
4. You don't check for division by zero issues.

Here is the corrected code with some more minor modifications *(untested)*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* #include <math.h> Unused header */

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int num1, num2, result;
    char op1;

    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Program requires exactly 3 arguments (excluding program name), Too %s given; Exiting...\n", argc < 4 ? "few" : "many");
        return -1;
    }

    if(sscanf(argv[1], "%d", &num1) == 1 &&
       sscanf(argv[2], "%c", &op1 ) == 1 &&
       sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &num2) == 1)
    {
        switch (op1)
        {
            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                break;

            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                break;

            case 'x':
                result = num1 * num2;
                break;

            case '/':
                if(num2 == 0)
                {
                    fputs("Division by zero is not possible; Exiting...", stderr);
                    return -2;
                }
                result = num1 / num2;
                break;

            case '%':
                if(num2 == 0)
                {
                    fputs("Division by zero is not possible; Exiting...", stderr);
                    return -3;
                }
                result = num1 % num2;
                break;

            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Invalid operator '%c'; Exiting...\n", op1);
                return -4;
        }

        printf("Result = %d\n", result);
    }
    else
    {
        fputs("Failed to parse arguments successfully; Exiting...", stderr);
        return -5;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Oh, and the shell has some special characters that do stuff. To avoid issues, wrap each argument with `"` like:

```
./main "1" "+" "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `sscanf()` given every part of the expression is in a separate string already:

```
if (argc == 4){
    num1 = atoi(argv[1]);
    op1 = argv[2][0];
    num2 = atoi(argv[3]);
}
```

Comment: In order to use atoi, I need to  #include <iostream>. I use Xcode to write this code. For some reason, it says can't find iostream.

Comment: @AlexM iostream is c++, not c. Include stdlib.h instead

Comment: @trojanfoe Because your code does (almost) the same thing as the OP's. And judging by the `Input Error!!!` as the output [even after the OP changed the second `scanf` to `sscanf`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449101/command-line-calculator-in-c-what-is-wrong/36450045#comment60510977_36449101) suggests that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @CoolGuy Well until you can tell me where the error is you cannot state that my answer doesn't solve the OPs problem.  You are relying on the statements of the OP, rather than the code itself.

Comment: It's because the second sscanf uses `%c`, and string pointer was passed instead. @trojanfoe correctly passes in the first character.